# How to set function as WindowScrollWheelFcn in guide gui

Tags: matlab-guide, mousewheel

I create guide gui(not programmatically) in matlab(R2015a). It contain a button to load images and axes to show image. when I load images I want to change the axes picture via mouse scroll.

Is there any Idea to change picture via mouse scroll wheel?

regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, what you are trying to do, but find a small example below.
The trick is using callback functions:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-definition.html

```
function test()

global img1;
global img2;
global img3;

img1 = imread(['icons' filesep 'calculation.png']);
img2 = imread(['icons' filesep 'calibration.png']);
img3 = imread(['icons' filesep 'gearwheels.png']);


fh=figure;
subplot(2,1,1),plot(rand(20));
subplot(2,1,2),plot(rand(10));

set(fh,'windowscrollWheelFcn', @showImage);
set(fh,'Windowbuttonupfcn', 'gca');

end

function showImage(~,~)

persistent ind;

global img1;
global img2;
global img3;    

if isempty(ind) || ind > 3
    ind = 1;
else
    ind = ind + 1;
end;

switch ind
    case 1
        imshow(img1);
    case 2
        imshow(img2);
    case 3
        imshow(img3);
    otherwise
        imshow(img1);
end;

end
```

I created a figure with two subplots. When you press the mouse button on one of the subplots, the one is selected:

`set(fh,'Windowbuttonupfcn', 'gca');`

When you scroll with the mouse wheel the function `showImage` is called:

`set(fh,'windowscrollWheelFcn', @showImage);`

This function does all the work for you. 
In the example I used a persistent variable to switch through the loaded images, which are loaded in function `test` and stored in three global variables.

It's also possible to give an additional argument to function `showImage`, to hand over the index of the requested image:

`set(fh,'windowscrollWheelFcn', {@showImage, ind});`
`function showImage(~,~,ind)`